# how to run awk twice across the same file

Tags: awk

I have a log file with user_id's and another column with contest results.
I would like to:

1. find all the user_ids of the users who won
2. given those user_id's, return ALL the log entries for those users

Example:

log.csv

```
id,user_id,winner,page_id
1,user_1,win,1
2,user_1,,10
3,user_2,,1
4,user_2,,2
5,user_4,win,10
6,user_5,,2
7,user_5,win,3
```

Given a log file like this, I'm currently doing this as a two-step process:

Step 1: Return each row mentioning the word 'win'

```
/win/ {
    FS=","

    # To make unique, store user_id's in array
    n[$2] = 0
}

# Print the unique array keys
END{
    for (x in n)
        print x
}
```

This yields:

```
user_1
user_4
user_5
```

I save this output in the file `output.txt`

Then, I pass that file and the original log file into another awk file:

```
NR == FNR{
    n[$1] = 0   # Set the user ID to the array
    next        # Go to the next file
}
{
    FS=","
    if($2 in n){
        print $0
    }
}
```

This returns the correct output (all rows for each of the user_id's that won):

```
1,user_1,win,1
2,user_1,,10
5,user_4,win,10
6,user_5,,2
7,user_5,win,3
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? With a single awk file?

Comment: Would this shell script work for you? `for u in $(grep win input.log | awk -F, '{print $2}'); do grep "$u" input.log; done`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using mawk for speed. I'd like to avoid shell loops; I've got TB of data. Thanks @jayhendren

Comment: There's nothing to stop you simply reading the same file twice: how about  `mawk -F, 'NR==FNR {if ($3=="win") winners[$2]++; next}; $2 in winners' file file` for example?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. This is blazing fast compared to everything else I've tried (see my comment below) and comes in at just under a second for my test file (420k+ lines). It's what I'm now using.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544105/awk-go-through-the-file-twice-doing-different-tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two arrays:

```
awk -F, '{a[$0]=$2;if($3=="win")b[$2]++}END{for(i in a){if(b[a[i]])print i}}'
```

Comment: I should add that your one liner is quite a bit more compact, but running using mawk, the total time to process 420k lines (160+MB file) was around 2.533s. The individual times of my two scripts when combined was: 1.213s. That's a 2x improvement using my scripts. I'll keep it the chosen answer, but I'll have to use my original scripts. Thanks for your beautiful answer :)

Comment: @zbinsd that's most probably because here the whole file is stored in the memory (in fact even more then one file), and memory operations cost some time. However I don't see a way to improve it. The bigger file is, the worse this solution is. For smaller files running two `awk` processes should be slower as time of `fork`s would be important.

Answer (score 8):

Rather late for this, but for posterity, I'd like to point out that you can do this:

```
awk '
   {
       # do first pass stuff
   }
   
   END
   {
       while(getline < FILENAME)
       {    
           # do second pass stuff
       }
       close(FILENAME)
   }
' file
```

If you want to do more passes, you can `close(FILENAME)` after the first while loop, then do a second one.

Comment: FILENAME is not set in the BEGIN clause because no file is being parsed yet. This is not a solution.

Comment: @Pillager225 - You are likely right that putting in the exact form I did was a mistake. However, the basic concept works. There are many work-arounds for your complaint. For example, putting the while loop in a `NR == 1 { ... }` block, or passing the filename as a parameter.

Comment: Sure, but edit your answer to a correct solution. First pass can be in the "parsing" clause, and the second pass could be in the END clause. That way the solution you present actually works.


Also, NR is not set in the BEGIN clause because no file is being parsed yet.


I just realized I can edit the answer, so I gave it an edit. Hopefully it gets accepted.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Yes, of course there is.  Just run Awk twice across the same file (as you said in your title).

```
awk -F, '$3=="win"{won[$2]} FNR==NR{next} $2 in won' log.csv log.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete single file gnu awk solution
you can just run it as :> **awk -f singlestep.awk log.csv**

```
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    #you cannot use FILENAME , since in BEGIN section you are not processing any files and the FILENAME variable is empty
    # So you need to use the ARGV
    while(getline < ARGV[1])
    {
        if ($0 ~ /win/) {
            # To make unique, store user_id's in array
            n[$2] = 0;
        }
    }
}
{
    if ($2 in n)
    {
        print $0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I fill `grep` is quicker than `awk` So if you have `GNU grep` with *perl extention* you can try

```
fgrep -f <(grep -oP "[^,]*(?=,win)" log.csv) log.csv
```

Without `perl.ext` you'l have to pipe `grep` output through `cut`

```
fgrep -f <(grep win log.csv | cut -d, -f2) log.csv
```

Or use `sed` (it seems to be quicker a little than above `grep`|`cut`)

```
fgrep -f <(sed -n '/win/s/^[^,]*,\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' log.csv) log.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), one may do

```
$ csvsql --query 'SELECT b.* FROM log AS a JOIN log AS b USING (user_id) WHERE a.winner="win"' log.csv
id,user_id,winner,page_id
1,user_1,win,1
2,user_1,,10
5,user_4,win,10
6,user_5,,2
7,user_5,win,3
```

But I'm not so sure that will be very fast on a huge input file. By default, an SQLite database is created, populated and queried in the background.

You may however do this in the shell directly too:

```
$ join -t ',' -1 2 -2 2 log.csv log.csv | awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '$3 == "win" { print $5,$1,$6,$7 }'
1,user_1,win,1
2,user_1,,10
5,user_4,win,10
6,user_5,,2
7,user_5,win,3
```

Again, I'm not sure how this scales to huge files.  Also, the input file has to be sorted on column 2 (which the example data is).